# How to parse JSON that is of type Mono<String> into a Mono<Object>

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux

I have the following JSON below. This JSON is what is returned back after I make the WebClient call to an API which is also shown below.

Once the response comes back as a Mono<String>, I need to parse it into my desired format and convert it into a Mono<Object>, for example using `JsonSanitizer.sanitize` to convert my String into an Object (which is how I did it via RestTemplate) but in this case it is a Mono<String> instead of just a String. All the examples I have seen uses `block()` to do the conversion, however, that defeats the purpose of using reactive. How can I make this conversion using Mono<String>?

```
Mono<String> response = webClient.post()
                .uri(new URI(url)))
                .body(BodyInserters.fromMultipartData(multiValueMap))
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class);
```

```
{
  "result": {
    "books": {
      "book": {
        "creator": "k",
        "created": "Tue Mar 28 01:01:50 UTC 2023",
        "author": ""
      }
    },
    "response": {
      "respMsg": "Successfully Completed",
      "respCode": "200"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create POJO class corresponding to json

```
public class ResponseData {

  private Result result;

  //getters and setters


}
```

and use the bodyToFlux() and bodyToMono() methods

```
Mono<ResponseData> response = webClient.post()
            .uri(new URI(url)))
            .body(BodyInserters.fromMultipartData(multiValueMap))
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(ResponseData.class);
```

If more customization is needed on JSON, the you can use `map` method after reading response body as string

```
    Mono<ResponseData> response = webClient.post()
            .uri(new URI(url)))
            .body(BodyInserters.fromMultipartData(multiValueMap))
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(String.class);
            .map(body->sanitizeMethod(body));
```